# Вырезать часть строки и адреса

Tags: php, html

Вот строка

```
http://skazkovo/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/shop.svg
```

Нужно получить

```
shop
```

Как это сделать на PHP?

Comment: идеи то какие то есть у вас?

Comment: Думаю сначала так сделать   http://skazkovo/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/shop , а потом так shop. Пока не нашел этих функций.

Comment: в php есть функция parse_url используйте её

Comment: @Alpha `parse_url` здесь не поможет. Она поможет определить протокол, авторизационные данные, хост, порт, путь, строку запроса. Но путь всё равно придется парсить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит попробовать **basename** и **explode**, если формат известен:

```
$name = basename($str, '.svg');
```

Если формат не известен то можно так сделать:

```
$name = explode('.', basename($str))[0];
```

Запустил в терминале две команды

[image: Запуск в терминале]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($str);
echo $path_parts['filename'];
```